# Matching repeating groups of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match groups of alphanumerics, optionally separated by the dash `-`.

For example,

- `ABC`
- `ABC-DEF`
- `123-DEF-ABC`

but not

- `-`
- `-ABC`
- `ABC-`

I've managed to do this in the backend (Java) with `\w+(\-?\w+)*` which works well enough, but it doesn't seem to translate to JS. I've tried many permutations with various flag settings, to no avail.

What am I doing wrong? The unit tests [can be found here](https://regex101.com/r/zWZ1I5/2/tests). Setting the sticky flag seems to pass most tests, except for the ones with a dash at the end.

Thank you

Comment: you can [**^\w+(-?\w+)*$**](https://regex101.com/r/sA4A8K/2) this

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Comment: @str I don't see the similarity. My problem was much simpler. Thank you nonetheless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
/^\w+(-\w+)*$/g
```

with match for start and end of the string, for it.

```js
var strings = ['ABC', 'ABC-DEF', '123-DEF-ABC', '-', '-ABC', 'ABC-'];

strings.forEach(function (a) {
    console.log(a.match(/^\w+(-\w+)*$/g));
    // with g                         ^
});

strings.forEach(function (a) {
    console.log(a.match(/^\w+(-\w+)*$/));
    // without g                      ^
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: When using anchors(`^`, `$`), `g` flag is useless. You can simply remove it without effect.

Comment: @Tushar, please see the different result

Comment: If you remove `g`, then `str.match()` returns the captured items as well.  You have to add `g` to ignore those, or change it to `str.match(/.../)[0]` (but watch for the null returns).